# tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020)

Tags: package-management, 20.04, texlive

I already tried what is suggested in the answer to the question:
"I got an error when trying to install a latex package trough tlmgr on ubuntu 20.04, verify_checksum: -5 ".

When I type this command:
`tlmgr --verify-repo=none install beamer`
I get:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

I went to the link above (https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) and as is suggested there, in the first place, i tried a "new installation" of texlive-latex-extra but nothing changed.
So I followed the guide. At the first point it says that the parent directory should be:

```
/usr/local/texlive/
```

and that, inside texlive directory, I should find a 2019 (or 2020) directory but the only directory I have is:
`texmf-local`:

```
ale@ale-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga:~$ ls /usr/local/texlive/
texmf-local
```

Eventually I looked for a "texlive/2019" or "texlive/2020" directory, but there are none:

```
ale@ale-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga:~$ sudo find / -iwholename */texlive/2020/*
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
ale@ale-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga:~$ sudo find / -iwholename */texlive/2019/*
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

I thought again that I did a wrong installation of texlive-latex-extra but after a reinstallation of "texlive-..." the problem was still there??

Answer (score 5):

The short solution is: this error is because you're using wrong repository version. Your TexLive  2019 is trying to use a TexLive 2020 ftp repository.

You should change to the right (correct) repository. Type this commands in a Terminal:

```
tlmgr repository add ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
tlmgr repository list
tlmgr repository remove http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2019/tlnet-final
```

After that you can install the package with this command:

```
tlmgr --verify-repo=none install dirtree
```

I added the `--verify-repo` parameter to avoid get this error: `tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5 for main repository`

Comment: This didn't help me unfortunately. The latex maintainers didn't think about backward compatibility at all it seems. Very frustrating.

Comment: I've test in my own computer and it works!

Comment: @SridharSarnobat which is your problem? can you show me a screenshot or the error message? I can help you

Comment: Thanks for the offer. It's been a few weeks and I've probably reinstalled the latest version so can't reproduce it now. I'll follow up here if I see it again.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat I have a hard time finding anything that latex maintainers _did_ think about. Building, writing, and debugging latex is a messy stack of frustrations.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend to install all the LaTeX stuff from official Ubuntu repository.

For Beamer use :

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
```

as it contains needed [beamer.cls](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=beamer.cls). You will get not too old 2019 version which is really enough to typeset documents. Newest 2020 is not needed here at all.

Comment: Thank you Norbert! 
Before I install texlive-latex-recommended, I would like to know if I'll still have problems (like the ones I mentioned above) using tlmgr for future installation of latex packages ?

Comment: You may have the problems if you want to mix `tlmgr` with deb-packages. Using deb-packages only is safe.

Comment: I've installed "texlive-latex-recommended" but I still have this strange directory tree:
`
ale@ale-ThinkPad-L13-Yoga:~$ ls /usr/local/texlive/
texmf-local
`
instead of "/usr/local/texlive/2019(or 2020)" as indicated in the [https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html]

Comment: I have never installed TexLive to */usr/local/texlive/* . Consult with its official documentation about removal.